# Calculate the integral of $\frac{1}{x^2 +x + \sqrt x}$

Tags: integration

How to correctly calculate the integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 +x + \sqrt x}dx$$

Edit: I tried to figure out if the limit exists:

Step 1: break the integral to two parts: from 0 to 1, from 1 to infinity.

Step 2: use limit comparison test for both of the integral: the first integral compared at 1 to 1/sqrt(x) and the second is compared at infinity to 1/x^2.

Step 3: conclude that both converge, hence the original integral also converges.

Step 4: (this is the one im trying to figure out, how to actually calculate it, because the limit exists).

Comment: What have you tried? I could recommend the substitution $y=\sqrt{x}$, but that only helps if you can solve cubic equations.

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum.

Comment: @J.G. I tried to break the integral to 0-1 and 1-infinity and use comparison tests, so i found that the 0-1 converges.

Comment: Edit the question to include your efforts. You'll get better feedback if you show that you really tried to solve it on your own before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others solve it for you.

Comment: @jjagmath edited, thats the farthest i got to.

Comment: If you do what @J.G. suggested, there is no more problem at $y=0$

Comment: Perhaps tell us where it came from.  Are you to calculate the integral, or does it merely ask whether it converges?  Is it a course where they expect you to use residues in the complex plane?

Comment: Hint expanding on my last comment: write the only real root of $y^3+y+1$ as $-a$ (if you want a formula for it use Cardano's method), so the integral is$$\int_0^\infty\frac{2dy}{(y+a)(y^2-ay+1/a)}.$$Now use partial fractions.

Comment: Solutions in the complex plain allowed. The complexity is too high to calculate it via wolfram alpha, so any prediction also allowed.

Comment: @RobertLee not really. Taking denominator as a whole there should not be dependence on constants. Otherwise, i wouldnt post the question, and use the complex-valued logarithm to calculate the limit. But its very close to my question using Cardano`s method as J.G. mentioned. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 +x + \sqrt x}=2\int \frac{dy}{y^3 +y + 1}$$

Write
$$\frac{1}{y^3 +y + 1}=\frac 1{(y-a)(y-b)(y-c)}$$ Use partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{y^3 +y + 1}=\frac{1}{(a-b) (a-c) (y-a)}+\frac{1}{(b-a) (b-c) (y-b)}+\frac{1}{(c-a) (c-b) (y-c)}$$ Then three logarithms to be recombined before using the bounds.

Look how nice is the real root of the cubic
$$a=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)$$ Then from Vieta
$$b=-\frac{a}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{a^3+4}}{2 \sqrt{|a|}}\quad \text{and} \quad c=-\frac{a}{2}+i\frac{ \sqrt{a^3+4}}{2 \sqrt{|a|}}$$

Comment: I need to accept your answer, although i wasnt familiar with Vieta`s formula. It helps a lot, thank you.

Comment: @OscarLanzi. $a < 0$ and I am lazy !! Cheers

Comment: @OscarLanzi. You want blue instead of read : I made it. You want to see $i$, here it is. Am I a good boy ?

Comment: That part is good. So then you have the complex fractions to decompose. Another answer is more complete.

Comment: @OscarLanzi. For sure, I agree with you. With time going, I started this approach which works for any polynomial of any degree factorable or not

Answer (score 3):

We have
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + x + \sqrt{x}} \ \mathrm{d}x\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{2}{y^3 + y + 1} \ \mathrm{d}y && \text{using $y = \sqrt{x}$}\\
\end{align*}
Clearly, this only has one real root, denoted $r$, where $r < 0$. Since $r^3 + r + 1 = 0$, we have $r^{-1} = -r^2 - 1$, so $y^3 + y + 1 = (y - r)\left (y^2 + ry + (r^2 + 1) \right)$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{y^3 + y + 1} &= \frac{A}{y - r} + \frac{By + C}{y^2 + ry + (r^2 + 1)}\\
2 &= A\left (y^2 + ry + (r^2 + 1) \right ) + \left (By + C \right )(y - r)\\
y=r \implies A &= -\frac{2r}{2r + 3}\\
B &= \frac{2r}{2r + 3}\\
C &= \frac{4r^2}{2r+3}\\
\implies \frac{2}{y^3 + y + 1} &= \frac{2r}{2r + 3}\left (\frac{y + 2r}{y^2 + ry + (r^2 + 1)} - \frac{1}{y - r} \right )
\end{align*}
Thus we have
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{2r}{2r + 3} \int_0^\infty \frac{y + 2r}{y^2 + ry + (r^2 + 1)} - \frac{1}{y - r} \ \mathrm{d}y\\
&= \frac{2r}{2r + 3} \int_0^\infty \frac{y + \frac{r}{2}}{y^2 + ry + (r^2 + 1)} + \frac{\frac{3r}{2}}{\left ( y + \frac{r}{2}\right )^2 + \left (\frac{3r^2}{4} + 1\right )} - \frac{1}{y - r} \ \mathrm{d}y\\
&= \frac{6r}{2r + 3} \left ( \frac{1}{2} \ln(-r) - \frac{(-r)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{3 - r}} \left (\frac{\pi}{2} + \tan^{-1}\left ( \frac{(-r)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{3 - r}}\right )\right )\right )
\end{align*}
Taking $r = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sinh\left ( \frac{1}{3} \sinh^{-1} \left (\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right ) \right )$ gives a numerical evaluation for the above term of about $1.8435267\dots$.